# django get view method name on permission classes like actions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom permission like:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print("view", view)
```

I am calling `list()` method of `ListModelMixin`.

Here when I print the value of `veiw` it gives me class name of the view. But what I want is the name of the method that is being called, in this case `list`.

In view set we can get method name from `action` attribute.

Is there anyway I can get name of the method not the class ??

Comment: Why you can't use the http method to check?

Comment: @davidm.. http mthod get is for both list and retrieve

Comment: I supposed that this could be the reason but you didnt mentioned the retrieve mixin

Comment: Also can you explain what are you trying to do and why you need to know the method in the permission class?

Comment: @davidm .. not only this.. If I use Mixins I may use post() or list() or get() or retrieve().. but If I use APIView I can only use post, get and so on. So I want to make permission generic here which is why I think mapping request method does not work.. If I could get  view method name that would be great

Comment: Not sure if the name checking is the right way of doing this. And also I'm not sure if the permission class is the right place of doing this. Said that maybe this link could help you: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You probably can't do what you want to do...

I think it's unlikely you're going to be able to achieve what you want here without some kind of a hack. The reason is, that `list` isn't really the view that is called. Look at for example `ListAPIView`:

```
class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for listing a queryset.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`get` is fundamentally the view that is called, and it then calls `list`. You could try and emulate what the dispatch method does to find the view that gets called (it uses `request.method.lower()`) but that's still just going to give you essentially the http-method.

#### But you probably don't want to do it either...

My senses tell me that, you probably don't want to decide what kind of permissions are appropriate based off of if you are doing `list` or `retrieve`. Even if at the moment, it so happens that all of your `list`s require a certain behaviour, and all of you `retrieve`s require a different behaviour. Almost certainly, a little bit down the road this will no longer be the case and this permission will become a complicated unmaintainable mess.

#### Alternatives

- Abstract away all of the logic about permissions into helper functions, and then write DRY permission classes for each View as needed.
- Alternatively, you can always check permissions as you call the appropriate `list` and `retrieve` methods. Write a decorator for each behaviour, and just decorate the relevant methods. e.g

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):

    @my_permission_decotator
    def list(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for you detailed explanation. I figured out a way to deal with it.. I created map with http method and rest framework methods. I didn't want to write permission on every method or class so wanted to create mixins that works for all